# Stylesheet breaking website

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

**UPDATED** The white bar is still there, however, the white bar is smaller and so is the image (the image is within the white bar) and the white bar stretches across the whole page. The white bar is above the particles.js and its background.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <center>
            <img class='' src='img/kaylumlogo.png'></img>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="js/index.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* ---- reset ---- */

body {
    margin: 0;
    font: normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #b61924;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5F64MpH.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#wrapper {
    border: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: anything in console?

Comment: try to add the type to the link tag: `type="text/css"` and also close the link tag

Comment: @TommySchmidt That has centered the image however the image is in a white bar above the particle screen now ( the white bar was not there before)

Comment: @TylerSebastian nope, nothing in console

Comment: @Kaylum but both the script and the stylesheet is applied now, right? for the whitespace problem refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image. Also make sure to close the img tag.

Comment: @TommySchmidt I have closed the image tag and removed the white bar, however, my image has gone back to being not centered

Comment: can you update your question and provide the new html, pls

Comment: @TommySchmidt its been updated :)

Comment: @Kaylum, what is that you wish to achieve? Only with the update is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: check the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5fdgtgsk/2/. i included comments. the image was centered but the surrounding div (#wrapper) was only 200px wide. so the image (200px in width) filled the wrapper.

Comment: @TommySchmidt i would like to center the image over the space background

Comment: take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#both-unknown

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: ```<img>``` tag does not need to be closed.  In HTML4, it used to require a closing slash, e.g. ```<img src="#" />```.  But in HTML5, the closing slash is no longer required.  So to display an image, all you need is ```<img src="#">```.  Also, why are you using ```<center></center>```? This is a deprecated tag.  [W3C gives suggestions on the best way to center an image](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block).

Answer (score 0):

Some of your tags are not close, some are closed incorrectly.

We always close a link tag within the tag with "/"

```
<link ... />
```

Same with images

```
<img ... /> instead of <img ... ></img>
```

I think "< center >" is deprecated.
With good semantic everything is possible.

It might solve your issue

Comment: center is out, you can use style="text-align: center;"

Comment: Thanks for confirming @mlegg !

Comment: tried using this, however, image is still aligned to the left of the web-page